# Mathematics: get X of Point between two points

Tags: math, equation

Imagine I have two points `[x1,y1], [x2,y2]` and I know, that `y1`is smaller than 0 while `y2` is bigger. And also `x1`is just one px smaller than `x2`. Now I need a way to create an equation that goes through both points and then I want to know what `x3` will be on the equations y0-point. // What `x` the equation will give me, when entering "0" as y-coord.

Do you know any equation to be like:
`x = ...x1...x2...y1...y2`?

Thank you :)

EDIT: 
This whole thing will be represented in a JavaScript script, to show graphs that leave the field of view. So please don't mark it as off-topic..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of mathematics.

Comment: But it's going to be used to show graphs on a webpage using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To find the equation of a line passing through two points***, say P1 = [x1,y1] and P2 = [x2,y2], you can proceed by doing the following:

1. Find the slope (gradient) of the equation, say m, which is given by the equation m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).
2. You can then make use of the so-called "point-slope form" for an equation of a line, which is given by the equation y-y1 = m(x-x1), where "y" and "x" are variables in the equation and "y1" and "x1" are any y and x values of a point lying on that line. In this case, we can take "y1" and "x1" as the point P1 above.
3. Once you have substituted the relevant values into the equation in point 2 (the point-slope form), you can then simplify the equation to give you an expression in terms of x or in terms of y, i.e. y = mx + c, or x = (y-c)/m, where c is a constant.
4. Finding the value of x when y=0 would then be as simple as substituting the value 0 into the variable "y" of the equation, which will give you the corresponding value of the variable "x" you are looking for.

***FOR EXAMPLE***, in your specific case we have that, given the points P1 and P2:

1. m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (y2-y1)/(x2-x2+1) = y2-y1 ...since x1=x2-1
2. Plugging m and the point P1 into the point-slope form, we get y-y1 = (y2-y1)(x-x1) = (y2-y1)(x-x1) + y1 = y2(x-x1) - y1(x-x1-1)
3. Therefore y = y2(x-x1) - y1(x-x1-1) or x = (x1(y2-y1)-y1+y)/(y2-y1) where y1 < 0 < y2, and "y" and "x" are variables in both equations, and everything else is a constant.
4. When y=0, from the equation above we have that x = (x1(y2-y1)-y1)/(y2-y1), which is a constant since it is only and completely composed of the coordinates of P1 and P2, which are constants.

The equation in point 3 of the example would be equation you would use for modelling in your JavaScript.

You may refer to [this tutorial](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) for an explanation on how to derive linear equations given any two points.

Comment: Very nice and right answer :) Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the x coordinate of the mid point between the two points then its: x = (x1 + x2) / 2
Which is the average of the x coordinates in question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how the find the equation for a line that goes thru two points?

Use the point-slope formula.

(1) y - y1 = m(x - x1)

m is the slope.  you can calculate that using your two points:

(2) m = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)

Pick one of your original two points and plug in their values, along with the slope m, into equation (1).  Solve for y.  The equation will have the following form:

y = mx + b

Plug in any value for x to get the corresponding y value.